# how to get the entire object with object entries method

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

i have given sample object like this below and i am modifying and assigning same object again with the below code

```
    value:
        id: "d5eb174c6bb34ab9a801d71465f71495"
        environmentSource: {id: "ca227b7be6e74008ad79115687b84c3d", name: "ashare12", edition: "v23", __typename: "Guideline"}
        category: "office"
        spaceFunction: "equipment"
        revision: 1
        conditionType: "HEATING"
        coolingSetPointOccupied: 1
        coolingSetPointUnOccupied: 3
        heatingSetPointOccupied: 1
        heatingSetPointUnOccupied: 2
        temperatureTolerance: 7
        relativeHumidityMax: 4
        relativeHumidityMin: 5
        realtiveHumidityTolerance: 2
```

where I am trying to replace the conditionType value `HEATING` with `Heating` with the below code

```
  Object.entries(code).map(([key, value]) => {
  if (key === 'conditionType') {
    value = getEnumLabel(conditionTypeData.conditionType, value);
  }
  return value;
})
```

and it is returning below output

```
    value: Array(15)

        0: "d5eb174c6bb34ab9a801d71465f71495"
        1: {id: "ca227b7be6e74008ad79115687b84c3d", name: "ashare12", edition: "v23", __typename: "Guideline"}
        2: "office"
        3: "equipment"
        4: 1
        5: "Heating"
        6: 1
        7: 3
        8: 1
        9: 2
        10: 7
        11: 4
        12: 5
        13: 6
        14: "LibraryEnvironment"
```

but i am looking for desired output like this below

```
    value:
        id: "d5eb174c6bb34ab9a801d71465f71495"
        environmentSource: {id: "ca227b7be6e74008ad79115687b84c3d", name: "ashare12", edition: "v23", __typename: "Guideline"}
        category: "office"
        spaceFunction: "equipment"
        revision: 1
        conditionType: "Heating"
        coolingSetPointOccupied: 1
        coolingSetPointUnOccupied: 3
        heatingSetPointOccupied: 1
        heatingSetPointUnOccupied: 2
        temperatureTolerance: 7
        relativeHumidityMax: 4
        relativeHumidityMin: 5
        realtiveHumidityTolerance: 2
```

Could any one please help on this how get the entire object from object.entries or any other way to do this that would be grateful to me

many thanks in advance

Update : this will be actual function where i am doing this

```
 const environmentSourceTypeOptions = 
     environmentSourceTypeData.libraryEnvironment.map(code => ({
label: `${code.environmentSource.name} ,
        ${code.environmentSource.edition} -
        ${code.category} -
        ${code.spaceFunction} -
       Rev ${code.revision}`,
key: code.id,
value: Object.entries(code).map(([key, value]) => {
  if (key === 'conditionType') {
    value = getEnumLabel(conditionTypeData.conditionType, value);
  }
  return value;
})
 }));
```

Comment: `objName.value.conditionType = 'Heating'`?

Comment: i cannot hardcode values that values need to mapped dynamically

Comment: `const someDynamicProperty = 'conditionType'; objName.value[someDynamicProperty] = 'Heating'`?

Comment: i cannot hard code like this 'Heating'

Comment: is `conditionType` a singular value?  If so, there are many better ways of doing this.

Comment: yes it is singular value always its key for corresponding label value

Comment: Then what's wrong with just `code.conditionType = getEnumLabel(conditionTypeData.conditionType, code.conditionsType)`?

Comment: Or, if you want a new object, `const newCode = {...code, conditionType: getEnumLabel(conditionTypeData.conditionType, code.conditionsType}`?

Comment: I just updated my question, Could you please suggest how this mapping will integrate there

Comment: Mapping is not going to be what you want, because mapping is for creating new arrays. This is a great question in that OP is providing examples of their efforts, I wish the downvote train would cool it. Let me know if I can clarify my answer in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using map, you're creating a new array instead of modifying an object. [Here's the documentation for map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) If you want to mutate an object (or create a new one) try iterating over the object's keys with [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach). Here is an example that mutates the original:

```js
const widget = {
  id: "d5eb174c6bb34ab9a801d71465f71495",
  environmentSource: {
    id: "ca227b7be6e74008ad79115687b84c3d",
    name: "ashare12",
    edition: "v23",
    __typename: "Guideline"
  },
  category: "office",
  spaceFunction: "equipment",
  revision: 1,
  conditionType: "HEATING",
  coolingSetPointOccupied: 1,
  coolingSetPointUnOccupied: 3,
  heatingSetPointOccupied: 1,
  heatingSetPointUnOccupied: 2,
  temperatureTolerance: 7,
  relativeHumidityMax: 4,
  relativeHumidityMin: 5,
  realtiveHumidityTolerance: 2
};

Object.entries(widget).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (key === 'conditionType') {
    widget[key] = getEnumLabel(key, value)
  }
});

// without seeing your code, I opted to write a simple function that formats the value as you expect it. I'm using lodash because lodash makes life easy.
function getEnumLabel(type, value) {
  return _.capitalize(value);
}

console.log('result:');
console.log(widget);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In my very humble opinion, lodash is the only dependency I never regret adding to a project. It's super helpful and was a life saver before ES5 prototype functions like forEach were well-supported.

Comment: What advantage does iterating the keys have over setting `conditionType` directly?

Comment: The advantage is answering the question in the way OP asked. You could absolutely perform an if statement to check for the key, then update its value.

Comment: I have a very different idea of what an answer is about, I guess.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to do it:

```js
// main operation
const environmentSourceTypeOptions = 
  environmentSourceTypeData .libraryEnvironment .map(code => ({
    label: `${code .environmentSource .name}, ${code .environmentSource .edition} - ${code .category} - ${code .spaceFunction} - Rev ${code .revision}`,
    key: code.id,
    value: {
      ... code,
      conditionType: getEnumLabel (conditionTypeData .conditionType, code .conditionType)
    }
 }));

console .log (environmentSourceTypeOptions)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script>
// Dummy implementation and data for `getEnumLabel`
const conditionTypeData = {conditionType: { HEATING: 'Heating' }}
const getEnumLabel = (vals, value) => vals [value]

// Data
const environmentSourceTypeData = {libraryEnvironment: [{id: "d5eb174c6bb34ab9a801d71465f71495", environmentSource: {id: "ca227b7be6e74008ad79115687b84c3d", name: "ashare12", edition: "v23", __typename: "Guideline"}, category: "office", spaceFunction: "equipment", revision: 1, conditionType: "HEATING", coolingSetPointOccupied: 1, coolingSetPointUnOccupied: 3, heatingSetPointOccupied: 1, heatingSetPointUnOccupied: 2, temperatureTolerance: 7, relativeHumidityMax: 4, relativeHumidityMin: 5, realtiveHumidityTolerance: 2}]}
</script>
```

The only important part here is in the node `value`, where we just do a simple object creation: `{... code, conditionType: getEnumLabel (conditionTypeData .conditionType, code .conditionType)}`.

You simply don't need to iterate over all the keys individually to do this.

Comment: @EnigmaState: I'm curious whether you've seen this and if it meets your needs.  I'm trying to understand if there is some important reason you want to iterate over the entries of your object.